# Copying files/folder from original repo to forked one

Tags: git, github

I cloned Original Repo **A** after adding remote Upstreams/fetch etc. I then forked A which we call **F**. Now I made changes in files of A and ran `git add` command to add them. I tried to push them and got `403` error which made me realised I made changes in wrong folder.

Now I cloned F on machine now. Is it Ok if I just copy edited files from **A** to **F** and push them on my own forked folder or I make changes manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `F` is a fork of `A`, you can just continue to use your local clone of `A` to push to `F`. To do that, you simply need to add your fork as a remote:

```
git remote add fork git@github.com:user/fork.git
```

Then you can do `git fetch fork` to fetch from your fork, and `git push fork master` to push to the master branch of the fork instead of the original repository.

If you prefer to have your fork as the repository named `origin`, you can also rename them and give the original repository `A` the name `upstream`. That is how the repositories are traditionally named. To rename them, you can do this:

```
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote rename fork origin
```

Now, your fork is named `origin`, and the fork’s original repository A is available as `upstream`.

Comment: I don't have commit/push rights to `A`. All I want that I send changes to `F`. Do I still need to apply same process.

Comment: >if you prefer to have your fork as the repository named origin

What difference will it make? All I want that owner of `A` can merge changes of `F` later

Comment: Renaming the remotes is a purely visual process; it makes no difference to the functionality. You could name the remotes “A” and “F” even. As mentioned at the top, you will need to add your fork as a remote to your local repository. After that, you can directly push to it and continue to work with it; everything else is purely optional.